# Updating a Layout class

Tags: android, layout, runnable, layout-inflater

My problem is, that I have a `Layout` class called by an `Inflater` and I want to run a method from this class to update a picture every few seconds.

I wanted to do this with handlers and the `run()` method, but my problem is, the picture only updates itself when I am interacting with the screen (clicking my only button).

Do you know what I did wrong?

Here is my `GameLayout` class:

```
package de.undeadleech.frogjump;

public class GameLayout extends View implements Runnable
{
private Sprite sprite;
private Bitmap bmp;
private Handler handler = new Handler();

public GameLayout(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.froschanimation);
    sprite = new Sprite(bmp, 0, 0, 400, 100, 5, 4);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    sprite.draw(canvas);
}

public void update(long currentTimeMillis) 
{
    sprite.update(currentTimeMillis);
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    sprite.update(System.currentTimeMillis());
    handler.postDelayed(this,  0);
}
}
```

EDIT:

Here is my `Sprite` class because you wanted to see it:

```
package de.undeadleech.frogjump;



public class Sprite 
{   
//private static final String TAG = Sprite.class.getSimpleName();

private Bitmap bitmap;      // the animation sequence
private Rect sourceRect;    // the rectangle to be drawn from the animation bitmap
private int frameNr;        // number of frames in animation
private int currentFrame;   // the current frame
private long frameTicker;   // the time of the last frame update
private int framePeriod;    // milliseconds between each frame (1000/fps)

private int spriteWidth;    // the width of the sprite to calculate the cut out rectangle
private int spriteHeight;   // the height of the sprite

private int x;              // the X coordinate of the object (top left of the image)
private int y;              // the Y coordinate of the object (top left of the image)

public Sprite(Bitmap bitmap, int x, int y, int width, int height, int fps, int frameCount) 
{
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    currentFrame = 0;
    frameNr = frameCount;
    spriteWidth = bitmap.getWidth() / frameCount;
    spriteHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    sourceRect = new Rect( 0, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
    framePeriod = 1000 / fps;
    frameTicker = 0l;
}

public void update(long gameTime) 
{
    if (gameTime > frameTicker + framePeriod) 
    {
        frameTicker = gameTime;
        // increment the frame
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame >= frameNr) 
        {
            currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }
    // define the rectangle to cut out sprite
    this.sourceRect.left = currentFrame * spriteWidth;
    this.sourceRect.right = this.sourceRect.left + spriteWidth;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    // where to draw the sprite
    Rect destRect = new Rect( x, y, x + spriteWidth, y + spriteHeight);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, null);
}
}
```

Comment: postDelayed(this, 0) looks questionable.   Why not just handler.post(this) ?

Comment: Don't know I copied it out of my other Class and I can try out like this if it works if I increase/decrease the time. But I think it doesnt really matter, does it?

Comment: Or better yet, use a delay period other than zero.  You doing some heavy duty processing.

Comment: Yeah that's right I should use a higher one (because I need it only every 5 secs) but still it only updates if I press the button :/.

Comment: Do you invalidate the the view anywhere to force onDraw to be called?

Comment: We might need to see the code in your sprite.

Comment: I create the view and then do nothing with it. I make a new GameLayout and that's it.

Comment: Try changing "handler.postDelayed(this, 0);" inside `GameLayout.run()` to `this.postDelayed(this, 2000L);`

Comment: And change `handler.postDelayed(this, 0);` in `GameLayout's` constructor to `this.postDelayed(this, 0);`

Comment: Thank you for the try but it doesnt change anything :/

Comment: Add `postInvalidate();` at the end of `Sprite.update()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of posting `Runnable` you should call `invalidate()` when you need to redraw your layout. Also you should update state of your `Sprite` in `onDraw` method as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I used invalidate() in the Runnable of my main game class and added the update method to onDraw() and now it seems to be working! Thank you for your help, it's pretty hard to get information about the methods which you should use if you have no idea which are existing.

Comment: @ChrisDürr as a general rule you should read documentation for at least for class, which you extended :) `View` in your case. Yeah, it's **really** big, but I highly recommend to read it. Eventually, you'll be surprised how helpful it is to know how things works in Android and will let you to avoid common mistakes.